# How can I define multiple data frames in a for loop?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

For example say I have some data frame, DF.

DF has a column called "Target" and it consists of factor variable target names such as "A", "B", "C" , etc. For simplification just assume it has only those three.

I want to define three new data frames,

for example if I did

```
for(i in levels(DF$Target)){
Dat.i=Dat%>%
filter(Target==i)
}
```

It would run three times but the final result would still be a single data frame, Dat.i , with target=C.

I want there to be three new data frames literally called Dat.A, Dat.B and Dat.C, each corresponding to the the specific target.
*not* Dat.i.

How can this be done?

Comment: you can use `split`, `split(DF, DF$Target)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly what you want, but I think the best way to do this is to use a list

```
Dat <- list()
for(i in levels(DF$Target)){
  Dat[[i]] <- Dat%>%
           filter(Target==i)
}
```

Then you can access to your dataframes by doing `Dat[["A"]]`,`Dat[["B"]]`...

If really you want to create different objects called Dat.A, Dat.B etc you can do this using

```
Dat <- list()
for(i in levels(DF$Target)){
  assign(paste0('Dat.',i), Dat%>%
                                filter(Target==i))
}
```